# How to view unnamed branch in magit "log"?

Tags: magit

We recently switched from CVS to GIT, performing the conversion with `cvs2git`.

I use `magit`, but I cannot find the combination of settings required to see all tags in the log view.  The closest that I have got is using `l`, adding `-D` and then `b`.

The tags are visible with the following command line:

```
> git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
...
| * f7b6bbb (tag: X_Y_Z1, tag: X_Y_Z2) This commit was manufactured by cvs2git to create tag 'X_Y_Z2'.
```

One suggestion was that `magit` may not be able to handle the unnamed branches created by `cvs2git`.

Is there a way to show such tags in `magit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that "unnamed branches" are refs that are not inside the `refs/heads/*` "namespace". Such refs are not considered branches by Git. In fact even "remote branches" (`refs/remotes/REMOTE/*`) are not considered to be actual branches.

You can view the log for all refs using the "Log all references" variant on <kbd>l a</kbd>. That uses the `--all` argument; unlike "Log all branches" (<kbd>l b</kbd>), which uses `--branches` and `--remotes`.

Comment: Many thanks.  I needed to include `-D, --simplify-by-decoration` and then `a`.  This was a combination I must not have tried.